# Apache cordova or react native webview

Tags: android, cordova, react-native, webapp2

At work we are thinkng about creating an android application to launch our webapp. (We need an APK)
So we are thinking about two possible solution :

- Using apache cordova to launch our client side code.
- Using react native (we don't will to recreate another client side app), so we will just launch our web app inside react native webview.

What did you think is the more suitable and the best ?

Thank's

Comment: knowing absolutely nothing about the app this is a very difficult question to answer. You should look at the pros and cons of each and whichever makes the most sense side with that option.

Comment: Yes, but me question is more about performance issue. Apache cordova embed like a "webview" for launching the application, so i'm just thinking if apache cordova will do better things that using react native webview component

Comment: if you are using a webview then android webview is sufficient and lighter. why react-native webview?